# Convert dictionary to tuple with additional element inside tuple

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

Let's say I have this dictionary:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

So doing `d.items()`, it would convert it to:

```
[('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2)]
```

But I need it to be like this:

```
[('a', '=', 1), ('c', '=', 3), ('b', '=', 2)]
```

What would be most pythonic/efficient way of doing it? Are there better alternatives than just iterating over a dictionary and building tuples for every key/value pair?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to iterate over the dictionary and construct each tuple. Using a list comprehension, this is fairly straightforward to do:

```
>>> [(k, '=', v) for k, v in d.items()]
[('a', '=', 1), ('c', '=', 3), ('b', '=', 2)]
```

Comment: For Python 2.x, use `d.iteritems()` instead of `d.items()`.